# How to find fields in a unknown table in a WinSQL?

Tags: relational-database

I know the name of a field, but I don't know the table.

```
 use "DatabaseName"
GO
```

SELECT t.name AS table_name,

```
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
```

c.name AS column_name

```
FROM sys.tables AS t

INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
```

WHERE c.name LIKE '%Company%'

ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;

In Microsft SqL, I got the result with above syntax, but I haven't got the result in WinSQL.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of database you're connecting to, but I suspect whatever it is would have some equivalent of SQL Server's INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. In SQL Server you'd just write:

```
DECLARE @col varchar(50);
SET @col = 'my_col';

SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @col;
```

Comment: I use winsql to query the data from IBM iseries